# Integration and substitution for logarithm

Tags: integration

This may sound trivial but I was a bit confused having lost touch with basic math. Can I solve this integration as the following?

$\int_a^b \frac{1}{x} dx = \log b - \log a = \log(b/a) = \log(c)$

The same holds true for $\ln$?

Comment: The integral og $\frac 1x$  *is* the natural logarithm.

Comment: yes, I am asking if the solution is correct or not for both natural and base 10

Comment: Your answer is true where $\log(x)$ is the natural logarithm.

Comment: For the $\log$,, there will be a fator $\ln 10$ (I suppose that $\log x$ denotes the decimal logarithm).

Comment: I see, thank you. Why does it not hold for the other logarithm?

Comment: For other logs (with base $a$), you need to factor out $\dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}$ since $\log_a(x) = \dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$. The rest is the same.